# Free Chess AI library, ideally in Lua (or something easily translatable to Lua)?

Tags: lua, artificial-intelligence, chess

A full game or application is not needed; just a core library that ideally can:

- be competitive against a human
- have configurable difficulty
- have customizable moves (I might need some unique moves that don't exist in traditional chess)

The platform is a closed system that can only run Lua, so I don't even have access to run a C++ engine via Lua bindings. I would need to translate the C++ to Lua, which I'd ideally like to avoid but am not opposed to if there's no other way (unless it's a boatload of code).

Comment: Did you google open-source chess engines?  There are more than a few (though they are usually written in C++, for speed).  Note that your "unique moves" may drastically alter the heuristics used for evaluating a position.

Comment: "competitive against a human" is kind of vague.  what rating do you want your engine to play at, on what kind of hardware?

Comment: Well, I just don't want it to be stupid, that's all I meant. What do you mean by "rating"? Hardware is PS3 using Lua as the language.

As for Google, I did a quick search but was mostly looking for Lua stuff. Stack Overflow is my new Google. :) Yeah, I know the unique moves could change things big time and am hoping there's an engine out there that is flexible enough to handle different moves.

Comment: by *rating*, Peter meant *ELO rating* : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system

Comment: Ahh, interesting, I have no idea then. I just want it to be adjustable so it can be tuned to be fun (it's for a simple game).

Answer (score 2):

Lua (v.5.1) chess engine is [here](http://chessforeva.blogspot.com/2011/02/lua-chess-engine.html).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a lua binding that allows you to use [UCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Chess_Interface).
Then you can use multiple engines.

I do not know of any pre-exisiting chess library bindings.... though I could be wrong

Comment: Unfortunately, the platform doesn't allow me to use anything other than Lua, so I would have to translate from whatever the source language is. But thanks for the tip about UCI, maybe something can be found from that info.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in writing a chess engine you might want to have a look at the [Computer Chess Blog](http://www.chessbin.com).  It documents the creation of a chess engine from the start including full C# code listings.